# What causes power steering "moaning cow" sound?

Tags: noise, vw, power-steering, golf

*( This may be a duplicate – but I did a search and "moaning cow" didn't come up ;-)*

I have a 2001 VW Golf. I just had a lot of work done on it and they "topped off" the power steering fluid because I had reported the "moaning cow" sounds. It went away for a week or so but now the sound has returned.

Can someone explain what might be going on? Also, is there a safety issue here?

Comment: Have you checked the power steering fluid level again?

Comment: Moaning cow?  Possibly related to [this](https://abovethelaw.com/2019/11/devin-nunes-demands-satirical-internet-cow-stop-making-fun-of-him-or-else/) issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like sucking air because of a low oil level. That is consistent with it going away when oil is added , and coming back when oil leaks out.